# Edge connectivity in graph

Tags: graph-theory

Let $\lambda(G)$ be edge connectivity.

Can anyone help me with those two statements if they are true and if so then why?

$$ \lambda(G) \geq \lambda(G - e) $$

$$ \lambda(G - v) \geq \lambda(G) - 1 $$

I think that both are true but I am struggling with proof.

**EDIT:** Edge connectivity is defined as size of the smallest edge cut in graph

Comment: @Salomo I added the definition into my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By Menger's Theorem, $\lambda(G)=k$ if and only if $k$ is the maximum number such that, for every pair of distinct vertices $s,t$, there is at least $k$ edge-disjoint $s$-$t$-paths.

If, for every pair of distinct vertices $s,t\in V(G-e)$, there is at least $k$ edge-disjoint $s$-$t$-paths in $G-e$, then there is also at least $k$ edge-disjoint $s$-$t$-paths in $G$ for every pair of distinct vertices $s,t\in V(G)$, hence, $\lambda(G)\geq\lambda(G-e)$.

$\lambda(G-v)\geq\lambda(G)-1$ does not hold in general. For instance, $G=(V,E)$ with $V=\{v_1,\dots,v_5\}$, $E=\{\{v_i,v_j\}\mid i\neq j, i,j\in\{1,2,3,4\}\}\cup\{\{v_1,v_5\}\}$. In this instance, $\lambda(G)=1$, but $\lambda(G-v_5)=3$.